# Lost my 3 star rating in Angry Birds Rio 8-5; is this a bug?

Tags: angry-birds-rio

After downloading the latest update (1.3.3) of Angry Birds Rio from the app store today, I noticed I was suddenly two stars short in the Carnival Upheaval stage. This, of course, would not do so I set out to improve my score on the level 8-5 to get back my treasured 100% completion rate.

After a few hours I gave up. I managed to improve my score a couple thousand points up to **73020**, but it still wasn't enough to even get me a measly second star. Weirder yet, this [video walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGBmmFXol7I&feature=related) for the level nets three stars at a score of **71480**.

I've completed all the levels without the Mighty Eagle and hope it hasn't become impossible to three-star the level without it.

Is this a bug or has the limit been changed in the latest update?
Have you encountered this same problem and discovered the new three star limit?

Comment: Same here - my three star score was 75,000 - now its a one star score and I can't even match my original never mind bump the star rating up!

Comment: Just got up to 77280 still only one star, this is impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Angry Birds' Nest](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/2011/10/mighty-eagle-now-available-in-angry-birds-rio/):

> It seems the 3-star minimum for Carnival Upheaval 8-5 has been raised. It was previously 65,000, but now I have 1 star at 78,000. Rovio did respond to our inquiry saying, “Yeah. That Carnival level limit is not correct. Will be fixed. Sorry about that”. If anyone can find the new limit we are curious (note, it may be impossible).